# show alertview after progressbar done

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have app for upload images to server.image is uploading to server successfully and progressbar is also working.but i want to show an alertview after progressbar is done... here is my code for progressbar.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
     float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
     float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];
     progress_bar.progress = progress/total;
     NSLog(@"%f",progress/total);
}
```

so My question is how to show alertview after progressbar is 100%.

Comment: `if (progress == total){showAlert}`?

Comment: Or it can be `float actualProgress = progress/total; if (actualProgress == 1.0){showAlert}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
     float progress = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:totalBytesWritten] floatValue];
     float total = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalBytesExpectedToWrite] floatValue];

     float actualProgress = progress/total; 

     if (actualProgress == 1.0){
         //showAlert
     }
     progress_bar.progress = actualProgress;
     NSLog(@"%f",progress/total);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not used the `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method?

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // show alert with UIAlertView or iOS8 UIAlertController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (progress_bar.progress == 1){
    //Add your alertview here. 
}
```

Comment: i have take float value so 1.0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84057/discussion-between-bhavin-ramani-and-pradumna-patil).